# Read the PDF files in line by line [Sequentially] using Java code and convert it to text

Tags: parsing, pdf, sequential

I need to parse the pdf sequentially. I used apache's pdfbox for parsing. But the problem is, **the output is not in the way that is displayed in the PDF**.

***For example:***

If the PDF contains "**I'm Parsing the PDF using Apache's PDFBOX**", then the scraped output is something like "**Apache's PDFBOX using PDF the I'm Parsing**"***.

***Used Code:***

```
public static void readingPageByPage(PDDocument doc)throws IOException
    {
        byte page = 1; //page the data is contained on
        try{
            if (doc.isEncrypted()) {//To check for Password protected PDF.
                doc.decrypt("");//Trying to decrypt with a empty string.
                doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
            }
            PDDocumentCatalog cat = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
            List<PDPage> pageList = cat.getAllPages();//Get all pages of the PDF as PDPage list
            PDFTextStripper pdfStripper =  new PDFTextStripper();
            if((pageList != null) && (!pageList.isEmpty())){

                for (PDPage pdPage : pageList) {
                    pdfStripper.setStartPage(page);
                    pdfStripper.setEndPage(page);
                    String pageText = pdfStripper.getText(doc);//Contains the content of the page
                    System.out.println(pageText);
                    page++;
                }
            }
            doc.close();
        }   catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF to reproduce the issue? While PDF contents indeed may contain unsorted drawing commands, PDFBox tries a lot to sort them. Probably you have a scanned document where text lines are slightly slanted upwards? Which PDFBox version do you use?

Comment: It contains client data and I can't share it. I used PDF BOX version 1.7.0. Then, it is not the scanned document.

Comment: It is absolutely legal in PDF to have no specific order of the text elements placed on the canvas. That's the reason why parsing is not sufficient; you would have to interpret the PDF. There is, however, a possible relief, if the document comes along as "structured PDF". In this case, you can parse the structure, which is more logic. In order to get some structure in the document, you may try to apply the tools to make it accessible (essentially PDF/UA compliant).

Comment: *PDF BOX version 1.7.0* - please update.

Comment: @MaxWyss *That's the reason why parsing is not sufficient; you would have to interpret the PDF.* - Current versions (1.8.3, 1.8.4, 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT) do that. That's why I was surprised. Probably in 1.7.0 things were different.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try checking with latest version.

Comment: @mkl even with 1.8.3 and 1.8.4 , I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: In that case I cannot tell without inspecting the file.

Comment: @mkl , let me share some other PDF file which is causing the same problem. [Sample PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/64e4ag8bzza70fz/pdf.zip). In that PDF **"Backlog vacancies included in the above mentioned total vacancies."** line is coming after **"Applications are invited from eligible Indian Citizens for appointment as Probationary
Officers (POs) in State Bank of India. Candidates selected are liable to be posted anywhere
in India."**.                                                          But it should come after the first table. I'm facing the same problem like this.

Comment: In the same path I have attached the parsed output as well.

Comment: I'll look into that later. Intersting indeed.

Comment: @mkl... Did you find time to look into the above pdf ?